# with mac's default php and apache installation, where is the www folder equivalent?

Tags: php, apache

When I used to use windows, i just install wamp, and put php code files inside the www folder and navigate to localhost/file_name.php to see that page in action. Now with my new macbook air, php and apache came with the machine, what are the equivalence of "put php files inside www folder" and "navigate to localhost/file_name.php"? How do I do what I used to do in Mac? (also I don't want to reinstall anything, no MAMP please.)

Comment: This is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: because it has to lead to a stack overflow exception in order to be in topic?

Comment: 'StackOverflow' is a programming related website, not a configuration help site, this should be taken to 'ServerFault', or similar.

Comment: i didn't ask for configuration, I am just asking how to get php and apache to run my php files. AKA, where to put my files, how to reference those files.

Comment: Exactly, which is NOT what this site is for... that has NOTHING to do with programming, it is to do with how Apache is configured on OSX and where you should put the files for your operating system specific installation.

Comment: if you go to any php programming tutorial, they will tell you where to put your php files, so you can execute them, how does that has nothing to do with programming? according to your logic, we should not ask vim and git questions here as well?

Comment: Putting files in a specific location on your PC/server is not programming related at all, it is not a programming question, it is a question about how to use apache/php on your PC/server. Go and open this question on 'SuperUser' or 'ServerFault', you will find people there that can answer this question.

Comment: this question has already been answered, the answer is /Library/WebServer/Documents

Comment: Yes, it may have been, but as soon as a moderator sees this question it will be removed. If you have a programming/code related question, ask it on StackOverflow... if you have a system configuration issue it does not belong on this website. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to find more settings and to change it but the default for OSX 10.8 is /Library/WebServer/Documents.

Some more information on how to setup PHP to work with Apache on OSX can be found at: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083